# Alter column data type in Amazon Redshift

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift

How to alter column data type in Amazon Redshift database?

I am not able to alter the column data type in Redshift; is there any way to modify the data type in Amazon Redshift?

Comment: "Create table as select..." And design your new table with the better column type.

Answer (score 162):

As noted in the [ALTER TABLE documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_ALTER_TABLE.html), you can change length of `VARCHAR` columns using

```sql
ALTER TABLE table_name
{
    ALTER COLUMN column_name TYPE new_data_type 
}
```

For other column types all I can think of is to add a new column with a correct datatype, then insert all data from old column to a new one, and finally drop the old column.

Use code similar to that:

```sql
ALTER TABLE t1 ADD COLUMN new_column ___correct_column_type___;
UPDATE t1 SET new_column = column;
ALTER TABLE t1 DROP COLUMN column;
ALTER TABLE t1 RENAME COLUMN new_column TO column;
```

There will be a schema change - the newly added column will be last in a table (that may be a problem with `COPY` statement, keep that in mind - you can define a column order with `COPY`)

Comment: ALTER or for that matter any DDL statement commits immediately irrespective of weather its wrapped in a transaction or not.

Comment: @RanienduSingh some databases do support transactional DDL statements. I haven't found an authoritative list, but most DDL statements in Redshift appear to work in a transaction. However, I think reordering the operations similar to the approach described here (rename, add, update, drop) may be more robust: https://www.simple.com/engineering/safe-migrations-with-redshift

Comment: It's worth noting that it's now possible to increase the size of varchar columns -- see user0000's answer below and the link to the docs (https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_ALTER_TABLE.html)

Comment: @Tomasz Tybulewicz would you please update your answer including user0000's answer? Your answer was correct at the time but I was mislead. Luckily I read user0000's answer as well

Comment: I don't know why the first clause format doesn't work in my SQL clients e.g. Postico and DataGrip, while @shruti pawar  's answer works.

Comment: ERROR: syntax error at or near "{" Position: 27

Answer (score 52):

to avoid the schema change mentioned by Tomasz:

```
BEGIN TRANSACTION;

ALTER TABLE <TABLE_NAME> RENAME TO <TABLE_NAME>_OLD;
CREATE TABLE <TABLE_NAME> ( <NEW_COLUMN_DEFINITION> );
INSERT INTO <TABLE_NAME> (<NEW_COLUMN_DEFINITION>)
SELECT <COLUMNS>
FROM <TABLE_NAME>_OLD;
DROP TABLE <TABLE_NAME>_OLD;

END TRANSACTION;
```

Comment: This is the method we use as well in order to avoid copy statement misaligned.

Comment: Keep in mind that any views that used to select from old table continue to point to old table. The `drop table` query will show the dependency error which can be but should not be bypassed.

Comment: Thanks for this, it was really helpful. I used it on a table with 31 million rows and it only took 3 minutes using dc1.large type. Great! I also used a slightly simpler form: `INSERT INTO <TABLE_NAME> SELECT * FROM <TABLE_NAME>_OLD;`

Comment: Encapsulating with TRANSACTION is very important

Answer (score 23):

(Recent update) It's possible to alter the type for varchar columns in Redshift.

```
ALTER COLUMN column_name TYPE new_data_type
```

Example:

```
CREATE TABLE t1 (c1 varchar(100))

ALTER TABLE t1 ALTER COLUMN c1 TYPE varchar(200)
```

Here is the documentation [link](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_ALTER_TABLE.html)

Comment: This works perfectly. A nice one liner that will not change the schema at all but update the data type. This should be the new updated answer!

Comment: example: `alter table myTable alter column myColumn type varchar(65535);` where myColumn was `varchar(255)`

Answer (score 8):

If you **don't want to change the column order**, an option will be creating a temp table, drop & create the new one with desired size and then bulk again the data.

```
CREATE TEMP TABLE temp_table AS SELECT * FROM original_table;
DROP TABLE original_table;
CREATE TABLE original_table ...
INSERT INTO original_table SELECT * FROM temp_table;
```

The only problem recreating the table is that you will need to grant again permissions and if the table is too bigger it will take a piece of time.

Comment: This is pretty similar to the existing answer from Wolli to rename and then copy the old table data into the new schema. Both will keep the column order, but this solution with a temp table requires copying the data twice. Once to copy into the temp table, and another to copy back to the new table. Renaming the table should be faster by only performing one copy.

Answer (score 4):

```
ALTER TABLE publisher_catalogs ADD COLUMN new_version integer;

update publisher_catalogs set new_version = CAST(version AS integer);
ALTER TABLE publisher_catalogs DROP COLUMN version RESTRICT;
ALTER TABLE publisher_catalogs RENAME new_version to version;
```

Answer (score 4):

You can alter data length for varchar datatype using the below ALTER TABLE syntax provided in the documentation [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_ALTER_TABLE.html). The ALTER TABLE statement can change the length of a varchar datatype.

```
    ALTER TABLE table_name

    ALTER COLUMN column_name TYPE updated_varchar_data_type_size
```

If your usecase is to change the datatype from one type to another, Eg: integer to varchar, varchar to date etc, you can use one of the below two methods

- **If column order doesn’t matter**: Create a new field with a new name and the desired datatype. Then, copy data from existing field to the new field. Drop the existing field and rename the new field. This method will move the column you are changing to the end of table definition.

```
BEGIN;
    ALTER TABLE test ADD COLUMN col1_new int;
    UPDATE test SET col1_new = col1 :: int;
    ALTER TABLE test DROP COLUMN col1;
    ALTER TABLE test RENAME COLUMN col1_new TO col1;
END;
```

- **If you wish to keep the field in the same position as it is**:  Create a new table with the desired definition, insert data from existing table to new table, drop the existing table and rename the new table. Apply all grants from existing table to the new table. To generate grant statements, you can use this view definition [here](https://github.com/awslabs/amazon-redshift-utils/blob/master/src/AdminViews/v_generate_user_grant_revoke_ddl.sql).
  After you create the view, run the below SQL to output the grant statements

```
SELECT DDL from v_generate_user_grant_revoke_ddl
WHERE objname = '<<table_name>>'
AND schemaname = '<<schema_name>>'
AND ddltype = 'grant'
AND by grantseq;
```

Insert these grant statements in the script below.

```
BEGIN;
    ALTER TABLE test RENAME TO test_OLD;
    CREATE TABLE test (col1 int, col2 varchar(10));
    INSERT INTO test(select col1 :: int, col2 from test_OLD);
    DROP TABLE test_OLD;
    <<Insert grant statements here>>
END;
```

Answer (score 3):

Redshift being columnar database doesn't allow you to modify the datatype directly,
however below is one approach this will change the column order.

Steps -

1.Alter table add newcolumn to the table
2.Update the newcolumn value with oldcolumn value
3.Alter table to drop the oldcolumn 
4.alter table to rename the columnn to oldcolumn

If you don't want to alter the order of the columns then solution would be to

1.create temp table with new column name

2. copy data from old table to new table.
3. drop old table
4. rename the newtable to oldtable
5. One important thing create a new table using like command instead simple create.

Answer (score 3):

This method works for converting an (big) int column into a varchar

```
-- Create a backup of the original table
create table original_table_backup as select * from original_table;

-- Drop the original table, and then recreate with new desired data types
drop table original_table;

create table original_table (
  col1 bigint,
  col2 varchar(20) -- changed from bigint
);

-- insert original entries back into the new table
insert into original_table select * from original_table_backup;

-- cleanup
drop original_table_backup;
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use the statements below:

```
ALTER TABLE <table name --etl_proj_atm.dim_card_type >
ALTER COLUMN <col name --card_type> type varchar(30)
```

Comment: This only works if you're changing the varchar length, not for other data types

Answer (score 0):

[UNLOAD](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_UNLOAD_command_examples.html) and [COPY](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_COPY_command_examples.html) with table rename strategy **should be the most efficient way** to do this operation if retaining the table structure(row order) is important.

Here is an example adding to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27607490/4106031) answer.

```sql
BEGIN TRANSACTION;

ALTER TABLE <TABLE_NAME> RENAME TO <TABLE_NAME>_OLD;
CREATE TABLE <TABLE_NAME> ( <NEW_COLUMN_DEFINITION> );
UNLOAD ('select * from <TABLE_NAME>_OLD') TO 's3://bucket/key/unload_' manifest;
COPY <TABLE_NAME> FROM 's3://bucket/key/unload_manifest'manifest;

END TRANSACTION;
```

Answer (score 0):

This may look tedious but works for me.

1. create a new table with desired column type first

`CREATE TABLE table_new (col1 its_new_type, col2 its_new_type);`

2. pull all data into that

`INSERT INTO table_new SELECT * FROM table_old;`

3. delete the existing table

`DROP TABLE table_old;`

4. recreate it by getting all data from new, which has the correct column type

`SELECT * INTO table_old FROM table_new;`

5. get rid of the new

`DROP TABLE table_new;`

Answer (score 0):

If you can't alter a column it is likely that the encoding is set to BYTEDICT, RUNLENGTH, TEXT255, or TEXT32K. You can find this by executing show table.

Step 1 : Change the encoding to something like LZO or any other encoding (alter table table_name alter column encode lzo)
Step 2 : Perform your regular alter column and change the column type or length.

Answer (score -4):

for updating the same column in redshift this would work fine

```
UPDATE table_name 
SET column_name = 'new_value' WHERE column_name = 'old_value'
```

you can have multiple clause in where by using and, so as to remove any confusion for sql

cheers!!

Comment: This is for mySQL, not Redshift.